# Error while extracting the middle of a string

Tags: java, string, substring, extract

I writing a code that searches through an HTML code and finds links within them. The lines in the HTML code have some unnecessary characters, so I need to remove the beginning and the end. This is an example of a line of the HTML code:

```xml
{s:"Hate Being Sober", h:"../lyrics/chiefkeef/hatebeingsober.html", c:"", a:""}
```

my code is posted below, and it works totally fine until i add the String bestUrl, in which case it gives me the error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
>   at Java.lang.string.substring(String.java:1904)
>   at CussCount.main(CussCount.java:32)

This is my code:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class CussCount{
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        String artist=args[0];
        String first=artist.substring(0,1);
        Boolean inSongs=false;
        String beginIndex= "h:\"..";
        String endIndex="\", c:";
        int one=1;
        URL discography = new URL("http://www.azlyrics.com/"+first+"/"+artist+".html");
        URLConnection xx = discography.openConnection();
        BufferedReader xy = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    xx.getInputStream()));
        String words = xy.readLine();
        while(words!=null){
            if(words.equals("var songlist = [")){
                inSongs=true;
            }
            if(words.equals("var res = '<br />';")){
                inSongs=false;
                break;
            }
            if(inSongs==true){
                System.out.println(words);
                int startIndex= words.indexOf(beginIndex,one);
                System.out.println(startIndex+6);
                int finishIndex= words.indexOf(endIndex,one);
                System.out.println(finishIndex);

                String bestUrl=words.substring(startIndex, finishIndex);
                System.out.println(bestUrl);
            }

            words = xy.readLine();
        }
        xy.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!!

Comment: I thin at main logic {String bestUrl=words.substring(startIndex, finishIndex);}, you need check for whether startIndex and finishIndex are not equal to -1.

Comment: Something is wrong with these regex `String beginIndex= "h:\"..";
        String endIndex="\", c:";`. They're not found, which makes `word.indexOf() = -1;`

Comment: Can you just show us some sample input and expected output?, and a few edge cases would be good.

Comment: When I run it without the lines of code that are causing the error the output is the line of html being red in, the number of characters in that the string beginIndex occurs, and the number of characters in that the string endIndex occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You were getting array out of bounds, because you forgot to read the next line after you set **inSongs = true**.  I added an additional readline along with a null check in the code block that prints out the song list.  The modified code ran perfectly when I used **eddievedder** as the input argument to main.

**Modified Code Below**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class CussCount{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            String artist=args[0];
            String first=artist.substring(0,1);
            Boolean inSongs=false;
            String beginIndex= "h:\"..";
            String endIndex="\", c:";
            int one=1;
            URL discography = new URL("http://www.azlyrics.com/"+first+"/"+artist+".html");
            URLConnection xx = discography.openConnection();
            BufferedReader xy = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    xx.getInputStream()));
            String words = xy.readLine();
            while(words!=null){
                if(words.equals("var songlist = [")){
                    inSongs=true;
                    words = xy.readLine();
                }
                if(words.equals("var res = '<br />';")){
                    inSongs=false;
                    break;
                }
                if(inSongs==true && words!=null){
                    System.out.println(words);
                    int startIndex= words.indexOf(beginIndex,one);
                    System.out.println(startIndex+6);
                    int finishIndex= words.indexOf(endIndex,one);
                    System.out.println(finishIndex);

                    String bestUrl=words.substring(startIndex, finishIndex);
                    System.out.println(bestUrl);
                }

                words = xy.readLine();
            }
            xy.close();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```